# azureDevops: create new policy for branch via powerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, shell, azure-devops, devops

"I have a project on Azure DevOps with two repositories: repoTest1 and repoTest2. On repoTest2, on the main branch, I would like to create and apply this pull request policy with the following script:

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = "2tkznxagtvfahaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$OrganizationName = "myOrg"
$project = "myproj"
$branchName="main"
$repositoryIdD= "74d57bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"



$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }


$url="https://dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/$($ProjectName)/_apis/policy/configurations?repositoryId=$($repositoryId)&api-version=6.0"

$json = @{
    isEnabled = $true
    isBlocking = $true
    settings = @{
        scope = @("ref/heads/$($branchName)")
        minimumApproverCount = 1
        creatorVoteCounts = $false
    }
    type = @{
        name = "myPolicyName"
    }
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -Method POST -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

it doesn't seem to work. The response keeps returning a value with two objects inside that seem to be my repositories. Another thing that I probably pass incorrectly is the repositoryId; I imagine there is a way to retrieve it dynamically.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the PowerShell script to get the repository ID via [Repositories - Get Repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/get-repository?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP) and create new policy for branch.

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$OrganizationName = "OrganizationName"
$projectName = "projectName"
$branchName="branchName"
$repositoryName= "repositoryName"
    

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }
#Repositories - Get Repository
$url1="https://dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/$($projectName)/_apis/git/repositories/$($repositoryName)?api-version=6.0"
$RepositoryInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Method 'GET' -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
$repositoryID=$RepositoryInfo.id

echo "The repo  $repositoryName's repositoryID we need is $repositoryID"

#Policy Configurations - post
$url2="https://dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/$($projectName)/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version=6.0"

$json = @"
{
    "type": {
        "id": "fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd"
    },
    "isDeleted": false,
    "isBlocking": true,
    "isEnabled": true,
    "settings": {
        "allowDownvotes": false,
        "blockLastPusherVote": false,
        "creatorVoteCounts": false,
        "requireVoteOnLastIteration": false,
        "resetOnSourcePush": false,
        "resetRejectionsOnSourcePush": false,
        "requireVoteOnEachIteration": false,
        "minimumApproverCount": 1,
        "scope": [
            {
                "repositoryId": "$repositoryID",
                "refName": "refs/heads/$branchName",
                "matchKind": "Exact"
            }
        ]
    }
}
"@
$response=""
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -Method POST -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Now it's much better, and I'm receiving a specific formatting error..: 
`{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF402457: The settings for this policy are not correctly formatted. Error: Error converting value \"$($repositoryId)\" to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]'. Path 'repositoryId', line 12, position 40.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Policy.Server.PolicySettingsFormatException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Policy.Server","typeKey":"PolicySettingsFormatException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}`

Comment: Hi @accountitalianu, it seems you didn't get the right "repositoryId": "$repositoryID". I updated the script to use [Repositories - Get Repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/get-repository?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP) to get the repositoryID. Please check if you can echo this line `The repo  $repositoryName's repositoryID we need is $repositoryID`.  If it still doesn't work, please share your new script.